# File object creation fails when running code as Junit test in Eclipse/STS

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, integration-testing, filepath

In my code, I'm creating a File object based on relative path to file in source code folder. Everything works perfectly when running this code under Tomcat.

When I run exactly the same code as JUnit/integration test using STS/Eclipse Run... and selecting JUnit, the test fails because it can't find the file based on same relative path that was working when code was running under Tomcat.

This is how the File is tried to be created in the code:

```
new File(getClass().getResource(relatativePathToTheFile).toURI())
```

I was trying to solve this by first figuring out the current path when the junit test is being run by using this code:

```
System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").toURI().toString());
```

It tells me that the current folder should be c:\CODE\myProjectName\bin\main, when running the code as part of the integration test.

the file I'm trying to access from the code is here: c:\CODE\myProjectName\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\nameOfTheFile.test

Based on this, I updated my relative path being used in code being run to following: 
/../../src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources/

By "/../../" I'm trying to traverse two steps towards the root folder and from there start to navigate towards resources-folder. For some reason, even this update did not solve the issues - I'm pretty sure that the path is right.

Maybe, for some reason, the path is just not accessible when running unit tests. Maybe, there's some Gradle configuration or STS/Junit configuration to be done to sort that out.

All my integration tests are in folder ../src/integrationTest.  All my code is in folder structure starting from../src/main/

Comment: `File(getClass().getResource(...))` worries me.  Imbedded resources are not (always) "files", they could be embedded within a Jar file, which makes then inaccessible via the normal file API. As a "general" recommendation, you shouldn't be trying to write to "embedded resources" anyway

Comment: The file I'm trying to access is certainly a file. I'm 100% sure about that. Also, like I said in the very first sentence of my question, I'm able to read the file perfectly when running the code in Tomcat. So, basically there should not be any problems reading this file. The problem is that somehow I'm not able to find the file anymore when running the same code under STS/Eclipse Unit-test runner.

Comment: And as I said `File(getClass().getResource(...))` is worrying.  It suggests that you don't understand the purpose of `getClass().getResource(...)`. While I recognise the fact that tomcat unpacks the WAR, not all servlet containers do

Comment: While playing around with this I was able to get everything working just by changing the old relative file paths to absolute paths. In the end this wasn't the perfect solution, so I ended up relocating my files according to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually fixed this by myself by relocating the files under src/main/resources. Previously they were totally out of this folder. After this, the same, updated, relative file path works while running the code under Tomcat or via STS Junit test runner.